# Finding a table in a DOCX file using the DocX library

Tags: c#, winforms, docx

I have downloaded and started using the [DocX library](http://docx.codeplex.com/). I have a document called `template.docx` that is being loaded into memory. I have a table in that document, that has the `id = 241`. I want to get that table by its id and add rows to it. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Load("template.docx"))
{
    int tableId = 241, i = 0;
    Table t = //here I need to find the table

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in produseFacturate.Rows)
    {
         i++;

         //here I want to add rows to the table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

Since, `document.Tables` is a list, I can call it like this:

```
Table t = document.Tables[3]; // I found out that the table index is actually 3;
```